# A word for a person who does something wrong if it's for powerful people

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for someone who is generally good but might perform without a blink of an eye a sin of sorts, if it is for someone who is powerful, out of awe and admiration for that person and their name in society.

So for example a social worker who knows a family is treating their children badly but despite the fact that the children beg her to help, because she knows the family is rich and powerful and there is a sort of non-spoken agreement that these people can get away with anything, she does nothing...

Hope that makes any sense.

example: She knew Madeleine was suffering there, but one glance at her mother in the hall, arranging her gold necklace reminded her that it was nothing to worry about. She left the house with a positive written review that was left with no weight on her conscience, and out of pure __________.

Comment: It almost sounds like a [pawn](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pawn), but I don't think that is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: She may just be afraid to intervene in the affairs of the rich and powerful.

Comment: Possibly a [lackey](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lackey) (definition 1.1), but it may be too narrow for your description.

Comment: emmm, not so much. I mean more like someone who is willfully participating in a corrupted act out of belief that since that person is powerful and "superior" they are the correct ones (despite that all evidence show otherwise).

Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Rebecca Your question is a good one, but it has been flagged and may get closed. This is common for new members. Please take the site [tour]. Please show us what your research has revealed so far. All single word requests require a fill-in-the-blank sample sentence. You can use the edit button to add this info.

Comment: Thanks @Phil Sweet for letting me know. I edited the post. I hope it is ok now.

Comment: One thing that's a little confusing to me is that in the title, you ask for a word for this person, but in the example sentence, the word seems to refer to the quality that this person possesses. Would you be satisfied with either type of word?

Comment: yes. Either type would be good at this point.

Comment: There is a very specific term for someone whose job is to protect someone or something but but chooses not to intervene (for whatever reason) when someone else is threatening that person or thing: **connivance**. The Merriam-Webster definition is "the act of conniving [where _connive_ means 'to pretend ignorance of or fail to take action against something one ought to oppose'] : esp. : knowledge of and active or passive consent to wrongdoing." As for the conniver's being "generally good," it's tempting to characterize that as _fair-weather virtue_.

Answer (score 1):

Check if ***sycophant(ic)*** fits.

Though it does not *explicitly* mean "*someone who is generally good*", it does mean someone who "*might perform without a blink of an eye a sin of sorts, if it is for someone who is powerful*". Also, the definition of ***sycophant*** does *not* explicitly exclude "*someone who is generally good*". You can also check one of the synonyms from ODO (reproduced below).

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sycophantic?q=sycophant):

> **sycophantic**
> *adjective*; *formal disapproving* ​
>
> (of a person or of behaviour) praising people in authority in a way that is not sincere, usually in
> order to get some advantage from them:
>
> There was sycophantic laughter
> from the audience at every one of his terrible jokes.
>
> **sycophant**
> *noun*
>
> The prime minister is surrounded by sycophants.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sycophant):

> **sycophant**
> *NOUN*
>
> A person who acts obsequiously towards someone important in order to
> gain advantage.
>
> Example sentences:
>
> An assortment of hatchet men, opportunists and sycophants gained
> access to the levers of power.
>
> There will be several servile sycophants who will come forward as
> ‘White Knights’ to regain their lost positions.
>
> Only the most sycophantic of the sycophants would even begin to make
> such a comparison. [In the past] there was at least a real enemy,
> there were real things to be done.
>
> **Synonyms**:
>
> toady, creep, crawler, fawner, flatterer, flunkey, truckler,
> groveller, doormat, lickspittle, kowtower, obsequious person, minion,
> hanger-on, leech, puppet, spaniel, Uriah Heep
>
> *informal* bootlicker, yes-man
>
> *vulgar slang* arse-licker, arse-kisser, brown-nose
>
> *North American vulgar slang* suckhole

Answer (score 1):

As a single-word-request, there might not be a perfect word that specifies "giving in to an authority".

More general words include

If the connotation is that the person doesn't want to do it but is doing it out of fear of reprecussions:

- *Impressionable*
- *Meek*
- *Weak-willed*

If the connotation is that the person is doing it because they have an agreement with the authority figure:

- *Corrupt*
- A *lackey* or *servant*

In your example, though you specify that the person has no weight on her conscience by her action of doing as the authority figure wants, which points to someone who isn't meek, but is more cold-hearted or unfeeling. In such context you might want to be more descriptive than a single word and specify why the person has no weight on her conscience.

"She left the house [...] and, out of pure **selfishness**, had no weight on her conscience because the repercussions of acting against the mother would have far outweighed any feeling of good-doing that helping Madeleine could have given her."

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of indulging the wrongdoing of authority is actually so common, that it is a person displaying the opposite behaviour who is called by a specific term: *whistleblower*.

Historically the failure to report a criminal offence was itself a criminal offence called *misprision*, but the term is now as archaic as the obligation.

A catch-all term nowadays would probably be a *collaborator*, which is capable of not only including those who actively assist or cover-up, but those who wilfully turn a blind eye, including through approval, blameworthy weakness of character, or a wrong ordering of moral priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

> [**traitor**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traitor) -  person who is not loyal to his or her own country, friends, etc. : a person who betrays a country or group of people by helping or supporting an enemy
>
> [**treachery**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/treacherous) - Guilty of or involving betrayal or deception

Answer (score 0):

[myrmidon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myrmidon) - a person who executes without scruples his master's commands, like the teacher the chairman of our department kept reappointing to the personnel committee.

Answer (score 0):

That person can be considered *meek*

> quiet, gentle, and easily imposed on; submissive.

The action itself may be performed out of *cowardice*

> lack of bravery.